# OAuth 2.0, what should it be returned in the authorize endpoint if the client_id is wrong and no redirect_uri is passed

Tags: oauth2, architecture

We have been working on a OAuth 2.0 IDP implementation, and during the implementation of the authorize endpoint, i couldnt find in the RFC 6749, what should happen if the client_id is not passed in the request or is invalid, and there is no redirect_uri in the request also. Should the server return a 400, with no body, a 400 with json? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is well explained in the request for change you pointed:

> The authorization server responds with an HTTP 400 (Bad Request)
> status code (unless specified otherwise) and includes the following
> parameters with the response:
>
> **invalid_request**
>
> ```
>            The request is missing a required parameter, includes an
>            unsupported parameter value (other than grant type),
>            repeats a parameter, includes multiple credentials,
>            utilizes more than one mechanism for authenticating the
>            client, or is otherwise malformed.
> ```

And this is typically the case you described, if the request is missing the `client_id` or the `redirect_uri` you should return an `HTTP/400 Bad Request` as described in [section-5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2) of the RFC:

```
  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
     Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
     Cache-Control: no-store
     Pragma: no-cache

     {
       "error":"invalid_request"
     }
```

Comment: I completely missed it. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I read Your question correctly You are asking about authorize endpoint and this is an endpoint that is opened in browser by the end user.

As You have no valid client_id nor redirect_uri you can not redirect the user back to the OAuth client application with appropriate error. In this case I strongly suggest sending human-friendly html error page.

> 4.1.2.1.  Error Response
>
> If the request fails due to a missing, invalid, or mismatching
>   redirection URI, or if the client identifier is missing or invalid,
>   the authorization server SHOULD inform the resource owner of the
>   error and MUST NOT automatically redirect the user-agent to the
>   invalid redirection URI.